# JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests

Tags: build.gradle, junit5, spock, pact, junit-jupiter

We are attempting to make some updates to our testing suite.  We would like to convert our contract tests that use PACT to use jUnit5.

When we update our packages such as our PACT consumer/provider and attempt to run the code we get this exception :

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 8.
...
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests
```

The current build.gradle file contains

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id "au.com.dius.pact" version '4.2.13'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.12'
    testImplementation group: 'au.com.dius.pact.consumer', name: 'junit5', version: '4.3.4'
    testImplementation group: 'au.com.dius.pact.provider', name: 'junit5', version: '4.3.4'
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
    testImplementation 'com.motorolasolutions.pnf:utils:1.0.+:test-lib'
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:2.1-M2-groovy-3.0"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.1-M2-groovy-3.0"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:2.1-M2-groovy-3.0"
    testImplementation('com.athaydes:spock-reports:2.1.1-groovy-3.0') {
        transitive = false
    }

    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter', version: '5.9.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.1'
}
```

We have tried messing with the plugin Id for 'groovy' and 'java' without luck.  Does anyone have any recommendations on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show at least your full Gradle file and one test class you’d like to be picked up.